# SqLite in memory database : CREATE TABLE does not work?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlite

When using this code on a SqLite file database, it works fine.

```
using (var ctx = new Test2010Entities())
{
    string s = "CREATE TABLE 'Company' ([Id] integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, varchar(50) NOT NULL);";

    ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand(s);

    ctx.Companies.AddObject(new Company { Code = "_1" });
    ctx.Companies.AddObject(new Company { Code = "_2" });

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var c in ctx.Companies.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Code);
    }
}
```

But when runnning this code on a SqLite 'In Memory' database (**Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;**) , I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing
>   database no such table: Company

Note this is tested with VS 2010, EF 4.4.0.0 and sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.84.0

**::: UPDATE :::**

As Simon Svensson suggested, opening the connection before any other commands does do the trick:
ctx.Connection.Open();

Comment: Will EF perhaps close/reopen the connection between ExecuteStoreCommand and SaveChanges? That will reset the in-memory database since the connection is the only reference to it.

Comment: @ Simon, you are correct. Opening the connection does solve the problem.

Is this a SqLite related problem ?

Comment: Your in-memory database is instantiated when calling SQLiteConnection.Open, so you need to manage the calls to that method. I've added my comment as an answer awaiting your acceptance. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when your ORM closes your connection, and reopens it. That will reset the sqlite in-memory database to its default state; i.e. empty.

The same thing happens with NHibernate unless you set `connection.release_mode = close` (the default is `after_transaction`.

I'm not familiar with Entity Framework, but I expect a similar setting or using the [`DataContext(IDbConnection)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292288.aspx) constructor which is documented as "If you provide an open connection, the DataContext will not close it."

The same documentation also states "In a System.Transactions transaction, a DataContext will not open or close a connection to avoid promotion." which may be a cleaner solution.

Using some Reflector magic shows that it's SQLiteConnection.Open that calls (via SQLite3.Open) sqlite3_open_interop (if you're using the NuGet sqlite package). This shows that you get a new empty in-memory database everytime you call SQLiteConnection.Open.